# Bot works in Web Chat but not in Teams channel

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I have created a sample Teams app with bot feature, cloning from https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/tree/master/src. It is running locally, using ngrok tunnel, and the bot is registered on Azure Bots Channel Registration.

The "Test in Web Chat" on Azure works fine, when I initiate the chat the bot sends a welcome message. When I type "hello" the bot responds with "Hello".

When I enable the Microsoft Teams channel, I click on the link on the channels page which brings me to a 1-to-1 conversation with the bot. The browser console already prints errors:
[browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZotjR.jpg)

When I type "hello" in the chat, the chat jumps to "Just me" channel. Bot only replies with welcome message, but not the expected "Hello": [chat screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUjMx.png)

The local ngrok shows conversationUpdate reaching the bot, which I suppose triggers the welcome message, but there is no text message reaching ngrok:  [ngrok sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOJxc.png)

The documentation [Talk to your bot directly by Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-test#testing-your-bot-without-uploading-to-teams) suggests I should be able to search inside Teams using the subscription id, but the bot cannot be found. Does that indicate a problem with how Teams channel is configured?

I tried packaging it into an app and import into teams, following the instructions in above sample repository. The app has tabs pointing to the same local ngrok tunneled service, these load successfully. But when i type in the conversation tab, the message disappears right away. Neither a converationUpdate nor the text message reach ngrok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Teams caching issue. If your bot is deployed as a full 'Web App Bot', you're going to have to delete and redeploy it. If it's deployed as a Web App with a matching Bot Channels Registration, you can just delete the Bot Channels Registration and recreate it. It's now permanently tied to 'Just Me' and even if it's fixed, the conversation will never show up in it's own chat, and will remain in 'Just Me'.

Comment: The bot is self-hosted and registered on Azure's Bot Channels Registration, it is neither a 'Web App Bot' nor a 'Function Bot'. Does Teams cache the association of Microsoft App Id with Teams channel?

Comment: I deleted the Bot Channels Registration and re-created it, it works perfectly now! Thanks!